# Error in Eclipse after executing project

Tags: php, eclipse

I am trying to execute my PHP project in Eclipse. It executes three lines of code and then gives an error saying

```
<terminated, exit value: 0>D:\Debuggers And IDE\IDE\eclipse\plugins\org.zend.php.debug.debugger.win32.x86_5.3.18.v20100603\resources\php5\php-cgi.exe
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- Try running `php -m` to view all the loaded modules.  Make sure that the zend debugger is loaded. [More info on installing zend debugger here](http://www.thierryb.net/pdtwiki/index.php?title=Using_PDT_%3a_Installation_%3a_Installing_the_Zend_Debugger).
- Make sure your project is in the right location (usually a folder named www, htdocs, httpdocs, etc)
- Read up on how to `run as web page` in eclipse pdt. There is lots of good info on that on the web.